# Mysterious Python global vs function scope issue

Tags: python, scope, global

```
def take_damage():
  health -= 20  # UNDERSTANDABLE ERROR

def check_health():
  if (health <= 0):   # WHY NO ERROR HERE, TOO?
    print("You have died!")
    quit()
  else:
    print("Your health is "+ str(health)) # HOW DOES IT WORK HERE?
     
  
health = 100
take_damage()
check_health()
```

Now, if I wanted to use this code, I'd start each method with `global health` to reach beyond the function's local scope. However, I'm at a loss as to explain why `check_health` doesn't throw an error in much the same way that `take_damage` will. Could anyone provide an explanation, please?

Comment: you can access a variable without global but you cannot modify it. `take_damage` is modifying `health` so it gives an error. `check_health` is only accessing the variable but doesn't modify it, so no error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `take_damage`, the assignment *defines* `health` as a local variable.

In `check_health`, the lack of an assignment makes `health` a *free* variable. The value of a free variable is taken from the closest enclosing scope where the variable is defined. Because `health` is defined in the global scope before `check_health` is called, no `NameError` results.

As an aside, the purpose of `global health` inside a function would be to change `health` from a free variable to a global variable, so that both assignments and lookups would occur in the global scope.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `health -= 20` inside a function, python searches inside the function for the `health` variable.
What you did is like doing

```
health = health - 20
```

but since `health` has not been previously defined in that namespace, an error is thrown.